# Start-Job with credential in custom task problems

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to develop a custom task using Powershell which needs to use `Start-Job -Cred` to switch to another user in places. Agent is running as user A and I need to switch to user B. Logging in to the server running the agent as user A and then running the script works fine - the `Start-Job` switches credentials and runs a scriptblock as user B.

Running exactly the same thing from VSTS in the cloud using the same (on-prem) agent server running the agent as user A fails with the uninformative error:

```
"The background process reported an error with the following message: ."
```

I have done more debugging and there is no other error message anywhere. It seems to be related to the `-Cred` parameter of `Start-Job` as it makes no difference what is in the script block run and if I remove the `-Cred` parameter, it's also fine.

- User A is in the Adminstrators group on the server running the agent
- Agent runs as user A

Any ideas?

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a try/catch block and see if an error is being reported to the shell.  Make sure you add `-EA Stop` to the end of your command.  In your catch block, you can use `Write-Output "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] $($_.Exception.Message)"`

Comment: Already tried that - can't get any more informative error than the one I mentioned. The error seems to be triggered by the `Receive-Job` in the `Start-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job` because the `Start-Job` fails for some reason.

Comment: Is the executionpolicy the same on the cloud device?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - how would I check that?

Comment: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

Comment: I can check but as I mentioned, this is all on the same server anyway. The difference is that the script is run via the VSTS agent service as user A (fails)  instead of directly as user A logged on interactively (works).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149737/discussion-between-theincorrigible1-and-plk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with Invoke-Command, for example (output current user name):

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "[password, could use variable]" -Force -AsPlainText
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('[user name]',$mypwd)
$scriptToExecute = 
{
$VerbosePreference='Continue'
Write-Output "$env:UserName"
# Write-Verbose "Verbose" 4>&1
}
$b = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $scriptToExecute -Credential $Cred
Write-Output "Content of variable B"
Write-Host $b
```

Comment: You were right - this works, many thanks. Do you know why this worked but Start-Job doesn't?

Comment: @PLK Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your experiences, your credentials are not being passed properly.  Try this method and insert it into your script:

Outside of your script, get the securestring object-

```
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Take the output of this command (where you enter the password), and put it before your start-job-

```
$Secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'above output'
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Username',$Secure)
Start-Job -Credential $Cred
```

The SecureString **can** be reversed by someone with know-how, but if the script and/or account is secure, then that doesn't matter.

Comment: Hmm, I can't do that, everything has to come from inside the script but I am converting to a secure string from plain text (retrieved from a secure password vault etc.) and then passing the `$Cred` exactly as you mention.

Comment: @PLK Are you converting the plain text using the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet?