# Custom TFS Task - Execute Powershell Script with specific credentials

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I wrote a powershell script for a custom TFS task (Build and Release Task). Now I need to execute some command with specific credentials. For this I create the following statement:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $mycred -Wait -ArgumentList "-file $taskDir\task.ps1" -RedirectStandardOutput C:\Temp\taskOutput.log
```

If I execute the command in the powershell, everything works correctly. But as soon as the command will be executed from the TFS service, it doesn't work. If I remove the `-Credential $mycred` parameter, the command also works in context of the TFS execution.

I guess that the problem is, that with the `-Credential $mycred` a new window was opened. And so it doesn't work within the TFS execution.

Anyone knows a better solution to execute a powershell script with specific credential?

Thanks!!

**UPDDATE 1:**

For better understanding I upload the full custom task [here](http://lexon.at/EFMigrator.zip)

Comment: What TFS version are you using?

Comment: In general I would recommend using a solution already created  - https://github.com/huserben/TfsExtensions/tree/master/BuildTasks.  If you want to have custom BuildTasks you can extend the github one.

Comment: When the build task is executed, it's using TFS build service account? Did you mean you want to run the task with another credential in the build pipeline?

Comment: I use TFS 2015 - but in my opinion the link is not relevant for my problem. @Patrick-MSFT Exactly, I need to execute the powerschell script with another user, because the task run an EntityFramework migration with integrated security. I upload the full task, as you can see in the question. Could you understand my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using Invoke-Command instead. A related thread: [Start-Job with credential in custom task problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218295/start-job-with-credential-in-custom-task-problems).

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "[password, could use variable]" -Force -AsPlainText
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('[user name]',$mypwd)
$scriptToExecute = 
{
$VerbosePreference='Continue'
Write-Output "$env:UserName"
# Write-Verbose "Verbose" 4>&1
}
$b = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $scriptToExecute -Credential $Cre
```

Answer (score 0):

When you queue the build, all build tasks should run under your build service account such as NetworkService. If you run the script a PS window pops up and closes instantly again. It's not able to directly run the script as a different user.

> TFS Builds allow you to access PAT token via a settings in build
>   definition. These are on the fly generated PAT tokens, so you won't
>   need to store any secret anywhere.
>
> For running the script at a developer's machine, you can ask a
>   developer to enter PAT or have an if else logic where you can ask him
>   for username password.
>
> More details please refer this  link:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/powershell#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api

You could also take a look at this similar question: [Powershell / VSTS Build - Store Credentials Independent/ Agnostic of User Running Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955978/powershell-vsts-build-store-credentials-independent-agnostic-of-user-runnin)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. My problem is, that if I want execute a script with specific credentials, than the powershell open a new window for the `Start-Process` command. But by executing this from the tfs build service, the process which is specified in the `Start-Process` argument will not execute.